# Can I get a data from PHP server to Android application with JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am not sure about understanding about JSON, PHP, and MySQL.

In my plan, I will create a web server and android application.The database server is MySQL. In my understanding, PHP can send data and encode it into a JSON array, how can I use this JSON array in my Android application?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/

Comment: After i installed that, what should I do? is it special function ? Thanks

Comment: i think .. this link will help u ... happy coding...!!!! http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand.

It seems like you're asking how to send JSON data using PHP.

Use the PHP [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) functions to convert between JSON and PHP arrays.

To send a JSON string, first convert the array to JSON using `json_encode()`, then `print` the resulting string and exit the program.

```
<?php
$my_array = array('this'=>'is', 'just'=>'an', 'example'=>'array');

$json_string = json_encode($my_array);
print $json_string;
die;
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. For your answer that I can conclude, i must send-receive data with server by json_encode and json_decode, right? Actually I really new for all, so it's look complicate in my idea. Can you suggest some documents which can read in more detail for me? Thank you

Comment: @Daisy: there's a lot to it, and PHP is just one side of it. Read the PHP manual pages I linked to. Also try Googling for phrases like "[json_encode ajax](http://www.google.com/search?q=json_encode+ajax)" and similar for tutorials. Here's one I found via Google: http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/08/15/jquery-json-with-php-json_encode-and-json_decode/

Answer (score 3):

following is PHP code...

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("Deal");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from CITY where CITY_NAME like 'A%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

here is a nice article [link](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/). i hope you like it, and if you have any question, you can ask, i will try to solve it as soon as possible.